# How do I get a defined value with Qmake?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, makefile, qmake

I have a header constants.h:

```
#define VERSION "1.2.3"
```

I want to produce myexecutable-1.2.3.exe. So how do I parse the header file to get VERSION in the qmake file?

(Also, that header file is generated dynamically and changing the header to use a value defined by the qmake is not possible)

Comment: This is not possible, but the opposite is. Define your version at the `.pro` file and use it at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how do I parse the header file to get VERSION in the qmake file?

This is not possible easily. You could look into the [system function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command-mode) with qmake to run external programs like grep and so on where available and something else where they are not, or you just send depend on it. This feels a bit fishy design though.